# Minimize object

Tags: javascript

I have a code like this:

```
var methods = {
    collapse: function(element) {
         modify(element);
    },
    other_method: function() {
         // ...
    }
};

function modify(element)
{
     console.log('collapse method');
}
```

Is it possible to minify `collapse` method to one line? So it should always call `modify` function.

Comment: You can just assign `modify` to the property: `collapse: modify`. (this has nothing, whatsoever, to do with jQuery or HTML).

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, thats a typo. Its ':' in original file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var methods = {
    collapse: modify,
    other_method: function() {
         // ...
    }
};

function modify(element) {
     console.log('collapse method');
}
```

Because we have function declaration (not expression), `modify` is visible when you declare the object `methods`. The thing which is done here is just setting `collapse` to be equal to `modify`'s reference.

This is the same as:

```
var modify = function (element) {
     console.log('collapse method');
}

var methods = {
    other_method: function() {
         // ...
    }
};
methods.collapse = modify;
```